# Power BI - DAX - Bizarre Behavior for YTD calculation

Tags: powerbi, dax

Trying to use a simple year to date (YTD) measure. But things are not working as expected.

**Data Model**

[image]

**dim_date** *(the weekend column is incorrect, but doesn't affect of principle)*

[image]

**fact**

[image]

The `YTD` measure is defined as the following:

```
YTD = CALCULATE(
    SUM('fact'[value]),
    DATESYTD(dim_date[Date])
)
```

which give me the following incorrect results for YTD.

[image]

It looks like instead of calculating the YTD for the weekend and weekday separate.

Given there are16 rows with that have a date that is label as a weekend as well as fact that all of them falls in the same year, I expect the `YTD` and `value`to be identical in the above.

Interesting enough, if I slightly change the DAX by using the `dim_date[Date].[Date]` instead of just `dim_date[Date]`, everything just works as expected.

```
YTD = CALCULATE(
    SUM('fact'[value]),
    DATESYTD(dim_date[Date].[Date])
)
```

Can anyone help to explain what is actually going on here?

The example `.pbix` file is here:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1y3ndL7yDE7T4x7Z2bPhMsa-NHRgGzYj0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [dax.guide](https://dax.guide/datesytd/) points out,

```
DATESYTD ( <Dates>[, <YearEndDate>] )
```

is equivalent to

```
DATESBETWEEN (
    <DATES>,
    STARTOFYEAR ( LASTDATE ( <DATES> )[, <YEARENDDATE>] ),
    LASTDATE ( <DATES> )
)
```

So what's happening is that since `Jan 10` is the last `False` value for `weekend` and `Jan 12` is the last `True` value for `weekend` and the `DATESBETWEEN` function returns a continuous range not filtered by the `weekend` evaluation context, you get all dates up to `Jan 10` in one case and all dates up to `Jan 12` in the other.

To make the measure take into account the `weekend` value instead of calculating over a contiguous date range, you can add that as a filter:

```
YTD = CALCULATE(
    SUM('fact'[value]),
    DATESYTD(dim_date[Date]),
    dim_date[weekend] IN VALUES(dim_date[weekend])
)
```